# Matrix and vector multiplication operation in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication

I feel matrix operations in R is very confusing: we are mixing row and column vectors.

- Here we define `x1` as a vector, (I assume R default vector is a column vector? but it does not show it is arranged in that way.)
- Then we define `x2` is a transpose of `x1`, which the display also seems strange for me.
- Finally, if we define `x3` as a matrix the display seems better.

Now, my question is that, `x1` and `x2` are completely different things (one is transpose of another), but we have the same results here.

Any explanations? may be I should not mix vector and matrix operations together?

```
x1 = c(1:3)
x2 = t(x1)
x3 = matrix(c(1:3), ncol = 1)

x1
[1] 1 2 3

x2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3

x3
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3

x3 %*% x1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9

x3 %*% x2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `` ?`%*%` ``:

> Description:
>
> ```
>  Multiplies two matrices, if they are conformable.  If one argument
>  is a vector, it will be promoted to either a row or column matrix
>  to make the two arguments conformable.  If both are vectors of the
>  same length, it will return the inner product (as a matrix).
> ```

Comment: well, thanks for the information. I hope we can have some matlab style that just give me error instead of doing something automatically.

Comment: Note also: R specifically does not handle vectors as either a row or a column vector, which can easily be seen by noting that `dim(x)==NULL` and `dim(t(x))==c(1,3)`. The misunderstanding arises if users assume that R defines row vectors because `c()` is seemingly defined "in a row." In a way, however, the R definition matches the mathematical definition, which also does not necessarily declare vectors as either row or column vectors aside from notational convention when working with matrices.

Answer (score 5):

A numeric vector of length 3 is NOT a "column vector" in the sense that it does not have a dimension. However, it does get handled by %*% as though it were a matrix of dimension 1 x 3 since this succeeds:

```
 x <- 1:3
 A <- matrix(1:12, 3)
 x %*% A
#------------------
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   14   32   50   68
#----also----
 crossprod(x,A)   # which is actually t(x) %*% A (surprisingly successful)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   14   32   50   68
```

And this does not:

```
 A %*% x
#Error in A %*% x : non-conformable arguments
```

Treating an atomic vector on the same footing as a matrix of dimension n x 1 matrix makes sense because R handles its matrix operations with column-major indexing. And R associativity rules proceed from left to right, so this also succeeds:

```
  y <- 1:4
 x %*% A %*% y
#--------------    
 [,1]
[1,]  500
```

Note that `as.matrix` obeys this rule:

```
> as.matrix(x)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```

I think you should read the `?crossprod` help page for a few more details and background.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
library(optimbase)
x1 = c(1:3)
x2 = transpose(x1)

x2
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```

As opposed to:

```
x2.t = t(x1)
x2.t
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
```

See documentation of `transpose`

> `transpose is a wrapper function around the t function, which tranposes
>   matrices. Contrary to t, transpose processes vectors as if they were
>   row matrices.`