# Better libraries in R for matrix operation

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

This question is related to a question I asked before

[Matrix and vector multiplication operation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025900/matrix-and-vector-multiplication-operation-in-r)

Specifically, I feel painful to do some matrix operations in R. For example, for the following code, there are couple of additional steps for me to make it run.

```
f<-function(x,A,b){
  e=A %*% x - b
  v=t(e) %*% e
  return(as.numeric(v))
}

A=matrix(runif(300),ncol=3)
b=matrix(runif(100),ncol=1)
x0=runif(3)

optimx::optimx(x0,f,A=A,b=b, method="BFGS")
```

- `optimx` only accepts a vector as initial value, so I cannot write x0 as a column vector like the assignment for `A` and `b`.
- my function `f` has some matrix operations, but it returns a scalar, `optimx` also does not like that (it treats it as a matrix class), so I need to do `as.numeric()`.

Is there a better way to enable me to do matrix operations in `R` like Matlab?

Comment: I am not sure this helps at all, but you can use `return(v[1])` instead of `return(as.numeric(v))` to pull the scalar value out of the 1x1 matrix R puts it in.

Comment: English usage note (sorry): "I feel it is painful to do ..." or "I feel that doing some operations is painful" would be more idiomatic than "I feel painful" ...

Comment: I am new here, for people down voting me, could you tell the reason? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not optimistic that you're going to find you what you want, and trying to work around the idiom of a language - rather than sucking it up/adapting to it - is often a recipe for continuing pain. A few thoughts:

- `c(v)` and `drop(v)` have the same effect `as.numeric(v)`; `c(v)` is terser and `drop(v)` is (perhaps) semantically clearer
- `optim()` (unlike `optimx::optimx`) doesn't complain about being handed a column vector (in R terms, a 1-column matrix), and works the same as in your example
- `crossprod(e)` is equivalent to (and faster than) `t(e) %*% e`

You *could* use MATLAB (you haven't told us why you're using R), or (if you can't afford it) try Octave ...